# null value passed from a iphone view to another

Tags: iphone

When I pass a string to another view  I have a null values.
My code is:

In  view `AddBarView.m`, where I have the string:

```
nameAdded = nameField.text;   //nameAdded is defined as NSString in AddBarView.h
NSLog(@"namefrom addbarview: %@", nameAdded);  OK it works here , NsLog return the textfild
```

Now in other view  AddLocationController.m

```
@synthesize nameAdded;
- (void)addViewControllerDidFinish:(AddBarView *)controller
{
    AddBarView *controllerAdd;
    NSLog(@"namefrom addbarview: %@", controller.nameAdded);  //here

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

the `NSLog` return a (null) value. Where is my fault?

tx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory to `nameAdded` string as follows and initialize it with nameField.

```
nameAdded=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",nameField.text];
```

**edited** 
Put the below line in the init method.

```
nameAdded=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nameField.text];
```

Comment: nameAdded is defined in the .h file as NSString and resctive property and syntesize. The NSLog(@"%@", nameAdded); return the correct value, but null in the other view

Comment: @doxsi It is because when you call it from another view the textfield does not get its value.

Answer (score 2):

See my this post I gave a **Tutorial** here for how to pass a `NSString` from one `ViewController` class to another [iOS - Passing variable to view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272864/ios-passing-variable-to-view-controller/11274661#11274661)

Answer (score 2):

nameAdded = nameField.text;   you had only retain the value. If you edit the nameField.text later,  nameAdded's value will be changed, too.
you should make a copy to keep the value.  nameAdded = [nameField.text copy];
Check that  in AddBarView's viewDidUnload function whether  you has released nameAdded or not.
 Otherwise, the two nameAdded variables are same object? please print their address.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are allocating and initializing the class that holds the textField. So it will always return you NULL value as the textField also allocated and initialized. If the class 'AddBarView' called before the class that access it, you could simply pass it to the class. Instead 'AddBarView' called after the class that access it, you may want to store the textField value in a Global String!!

Comment: Tx. how Could I define a Global string?

Comment: You can do that in many ways!! Usually, I'll create a C-file (holds .h file alone). Declare your string there. Import that in '.pch'. Now you can access it in your class :-)