# How to pass label value in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have two controllers A & B
In B there are one label and one string
In A i have write the below code

```
B *ObjB =[[B alloc]initWithNibName:@"B" bundle:nil];
ObjB.Mylabel.text=[NSString stringWithString:@"Add New name"];
ObjB.MyString=[NSString stringWithString:@"new string name"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ObjB animated:YES];
[ObjB release];
```

I am only getting the ObjB.MyString value in B , not getting the label text.Can any one help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the line `ObjB.Mylabel.text=[NSString stringWithString:@"Add New name"];` after the line `[self.navigationController pushViewController:ObjB animated:YES];`?

Comment: It depends on your need. you can make a Singleton class for Sharing data between classes. you can see my previous answer how to make Singleton class [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272864/ios-passing-variable-to-view-controller/11272989#11272989)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming that `MyLabel` is a `UILabel` (sidenote: avoid capitalized names for ivars - in Objc capitalized names are used [by convention] for Classes), the reason that the value is not set is because the view hierarchy of your `B` controller has not yet been loaded (ie your label is `nil` at this point). So you got three options:

1. Force the view hierarchy to load & then set your label:

   `[ObjB loadView]; // Note: Apple says that you never should call this directly (just to illustrate my point)!!`
2. Let the system load the hierarchy for you by requesting the view first:

   `id view = ObjB.view; // This is a bit of a 'hack' actually`
3. Just add another property in your `B` controller, set that and on `viewDidLoad` set your label's text (This is the best option in my opinion)

Comment: I wouldn't force load the view hierarchy. The view are lazy loaded for a reason, let the system decide when to load it. The second option of storing the data and populating the label when the system decides to load the view is much better.

Comment: @Stew Agree. And that's why I have the exclamation marks in my comments :)

Comment: Sorry, missed that the first time. I'd only offer option #3, the others are both solutions I wouldn't recommend

Answer (score 1):

The best way to pass data between two view controllers is to declare a variable in controller B, to hold the labels text.
    In viewController B's header file

```
    NSString *labelText;

//Declare its property and synthesize in .m
```

In controller A, before navigating to controller B, initialize this variable to the text you want, i.e. in this case "Add New Name".

```
B *ObjB =[[B alloc]initWithNibName:@"B" bundle:nil];
ObjB.labelText = [NSString stringWithString:@"Add New name"];
ObjB.MyString = [NSString stringWithString:@"new string name"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ObjB animated:YES];
```

Next in the viewDidLoad of controller B, assign the label's text to the variable which contains the string.

```
ViewDidLoad of B
MyLabel.Text = labelText;
//Assuming you have mapped MyLabel to the IB.
```

Also i use ARC for all my projects, so I dont use the release command.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
B *ObjB =[[B alloc]initWithNibName:@"B" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ObjB animated:YES];
ObjB.Mylabel.text=[NSString stringWithString:@"Add New name"];
ObjB.MyString=[NSString stringWithString:@"new string name"];
[ObjB release];
```

Thanks for your immediate response

Comment: Please follow @Alladinian's solution. I'm not sure your approach will consistently result in the view hierarchy being created before you set the property on the label.